# select from BindingList

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, bindinglist

I have the following Object

**PatientEligibilityObject**

It has One To Many relation with **PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties**

I fill the Child value into Grid like following : -

```
 Dim lst = PatientEligibilityObject.PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties.GetNewBindingList()
```

It fills the grid with All Columns in the Table **PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties**

*ID

PatientsEligibilityID

**DoctorSpecialtyID**

RegDate 
RegUserID

RegComputerID

CancelDate

CancelUserID

CancelComputerID*

Instead Of Column  **DoctorSpecialtyID**     i want to Display

**DoctorSpeciality.Code** And 
**DoctorSpeciality.EngName**

Notice that there is a foreign key between **PatientsEligibilitiesDoctorsSpecialties**  and **DoctorsSpecialties**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Datatable  filled using LINQ query in which i could  be able to select relational table >>

Answer (score 0):

Would the sample in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx)

where they explain how to modify columns in a DataGridView bound to a table, help you?
You remove one column and insert a different style column in it's place.

Comment: Thanks Martin,this example is general about customizing DatagridViewColumns , i'm Using **Infragestics.UltraGrid** NOT **DataGridView** , this Grid takes everything in Datasource which is a BindingList, so i need to change in the BindingList , may select specific columns and specific child. how could i do that>